# Do any countries have a 100% open immigration policy?

Tags: immigration

Are there any countries who will allow anyone to immigrate into their country and eventually become citizens?

Comment: The US used to be like that.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I think you should make it clear that you are either joking or expressing a personal opinion. The United States has never had an open door immigration policy.

Comment: @barrycarter: Best I'm aware the US had an open door immigration policy until the Civil War or whereabouts. It wasn't [until 1875](https://www.uscis.gov/history-and-genealogy/our-history/agency-history/early-american-immigration-policies) that the Supreme Court declared regulation of immigration a federal responsibility.

Comment: There are countries who allow anyone (including, perhaps, the most wanted criminals), to *buy* their citizenship. But NOT to immigrate.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - in all fairness, i would guess that it was due in large part because immigration in those days was naturally limited due to difficulty of actually getting to the US. And the population was very low so the more immigrants the better (source: playing Sid Meyer's Colonization :)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I was thinking of the Immigration and Naturalization Act of 1964, which formally opened US doors to more immigration. My thought was such an act would be unneeded if immigration were already open. However, you're talking about 100 years before that, so I'll have to double check CivCTP ;) (I know, I know, different game)

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy immigration was regulated by the states, but that doesn't mean it was open door.  I suspect that some states at least will have had racist policies.

Comment: Not a country, so citizenship is off the table, but anyone can move to [Svalbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard) without a [visa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard).  I'm not sure whether there a is a path to Norwegian citizenship for such people.

Answer (score 11):

As TimSparrow's comment noted, there are countries which allow people to ***buy*** citizenship. Actually, nearly all countries do including USA and Europe, but some are more choosy about who they accept/vet/reject than others - such as Mexico or Canada. On the other hand others are less choosy:

- Dominica was selling their passports to any comers at all.

  This was discussed in more detail here: [Why countries selling passports is bad?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13575/why-countries-selling-passports-is-bad/13585#13585)
- Ecuador: To immigrate, all you need to be able to show **is a guaranteed monthly income of USD $800 for yourself, and an extra USD $100 for each of your dependents**.
- Argentina: To settle here, all you need to show is a guaranteed monthly income of USD $850.
- Uruguay: they also require a guaranteed minimum income to immigrate (couldn't find out how much yet). But it's not trivial to become a citizen later, though nowhere near difficult:

  > Applying for Uruguay citizenship requires that you show proof that the country is your center of life. This proof can border on the arcane, as judges and immigration officials have requested library cards, receipts from doctor appointments, or proof of country club memberships.
  >   (source: http://nomadcapitalist.com/2015/07/22/how-to-get-uruguay-citizenship/)

However, there are no countries that have a 100% free immigration policy - they all restrict who can immigrate either by required guaranteed income (many Latin American countries); or skillset (Canada, Mexico etc...), or a hodgepodge of policies (US, EU).

Sources: [Five Countries With Easy Immigration Policies](https://wanderwisdom.com/misc/Five-easiest-countries-to-immigrate-to)

P.S. you can freely immigrate from one EU country to another, but that doesn't apply to non-refugee immigration from outside EU. Actually, not that freely as comments suggested - you still need a source of financial support.

Comment: It's purely a point of word use, and me feeling old, but isn't the verb to transit between two countries (as per your EU example) still "to migrate" rather than "to immigrate"?

Comment: @origimbo - beats me. I'm an immigrant (ironically) who's ESL, such nuances are beyond my limited English capabilities.

Comment: Searching English Language & Use, it appears there's no modern consensus among native speakers either, although implied differences might be either regional or political.

Comment: Migration between EU countries US also not entirely without restriction; EU citizens can't just turn up in another country and go on the dole.  They can stay for longer than three months only if they are employed, self-employed, self sufficient, studying, or a family member of an EU citizen who is one of those things.

Comment: @origimbo I don't think it's regional so much as logical.  *Im-,* derived from *in,* invokes the relationship between the migrant an the destination country, while *e-,* derived from *ex,* meaning *out,* has to do with the country of origin.  *Migrant* ignores both origin and destination.  The logical problem is that any immigrant is necessarily also an emigrant and a migrant, do you can really use any of the three words in many contexts.  This leads to confusion where *immigrant* and *emigrant* are often used in questionable contexts where the other is probably better.

Comment: TL;DR: English is confusing.

Comment: When you are talking about money, it would be nice to add information about current income in the country you are talking about. A US guy, looking at guaranteed monthly income of 800$ for Ecuador might think that this is easy. But with average monthly income of 500$ in Ecuador, it would be approximately 8000$ in US. The numbers are very approximate, but I hope the point is clear.

Comment: @SalvadorDali - the point I was trying to make is the opposite - you still need SOME guaranteed income. They don't just take in any randoms

Comment: @user4012 I got it. Was just showing that even if for american's this looks like you need a very tiny income, this income is actually 2 times above the average in that country.

Answer (score 6):

There aren't such countries to my knowledge, but Norway has a small territory called [Svalbard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard) that is completely open to citizens of all countries that signed the [Svalbard Treaty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Svalbard_Treaty):

> All citizens and all companies of every nation under the treaty are allowed to become residents and to have access to Svalbard including the right to fish, hunt or undertake any kind of maritime, industrial, mining or trade activity. The residents of Svalbard must follow Norwegian law though Norwegian authority cannot discriminate against or favor any residents of any given nationality.

Of course there's a catch to this seemingly perfect getaway destination. To quote [the excellent answer by @jpatokal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/45131/9009) on Travel.SE:

> 1. Located at 78°N, Svalbard's main town [Longyearbyen](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Longyearbyen) (pop. 2600) is by far the **world's most northernmost civilian settlement**,
>      and rather resembles Mordor after it has frozen over: lots of black
>      rock, virtually no plants larger than lichen.  This means an average
>      February day is −21°C, a balmy summer day in August is 3°C,
>      and oh, there's no sunlight whatsoever during the polar night between
>      late October and mid-February.  Also, you need to carry a rifle if
>      traveling anywhere outside the town due to the large and hungry polar
>      bear population.
> 2. The only practical way to get to Svalbard is Norway, which can and does enforce its own visa rules.  That said, once there Norway and
>      Schengen rules (eg. the 90-in-180 limit) do not apply, all you need to
>      demonstrate is that [you have the means to support yourself](http://www.sysselmannen.no/en/Visitors/Entry-and-residence/).
> 3. Essentially all private accommodation on Svalbard is owned by companies in Svalbard, which means finding a place to rent is tough to
>      impossible.  Now you could just stay in a hotel, but...
> 4. If you thought Norway was expensive, imagine Norwegian prices with a hefty bonus for shipping everything through some of the roughest sea
>      on Earth.  You won't get much change back from US$20 if you buy a
>      kebab and a Coke.

Also note that Svalbard [currently treats citizens of non-signatory countries the same](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Svalbard) as citizens of those that have signed, so it covers 100% of the world's population. It [used to be possible](http://www.aljazeera.com/archive/2006/07/200841012024779644.html) to become a Norwegian citizen after spending seven years on the island, but this "loophole" [is currently closed](https://www.sysselmannen.no/en/Visitors/Entry-and-residence/).

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article, Svalbard currently treats citizens of non-signatory countries the same as citizens of those that have signed.

Comment: You can neither buy land there nor build a house yourself. And private residencies for sale are too rare. Practically it is impossible to settle there. It is one of the hardest places to live. It is actually a place that deserves to be a ghost town.